PrismaClientKnownRequestError: Invalid `prisma.auth.findUnique()` invocation:
This request could not be understood by the server:
{"type":"UnknownJsonError","body":{"code":"P6008","message":"Accelerate was not able to connect to your database. The underlying error is: "}} (The request id was: 8b84e9d169420435)
    at Qr.handleRequestError (C:\Users\kethmark\thesis\node_modules\@prisma\client\runtime\edge.js:20:8003)
    at Qr.handleAndLogRequestError (C:\Users\kethmark\thesis\node_modules\@prisma\client\runtime\edge.js:20:7311)
    at Qr.request (C:\Users\kethmark\thesis\node_modules\@prisma\client\runtime\edge.js:20:7001)
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
    at async l (C:\Users\kethmark\thesis\node_modules\@prisma\client\runtime\edge.js:29:9280)
    at async POST (webpack-internal:///(rsc)/./app/api/auth/signin/route.ts:17:22)
    at async C:\Users\kethmark\thesis\node_modules\next\dist\compiled\next-server\app-route.runtime.dev.js:6:55038
    at async ek.execute (C:\Users\kethmark\thesis\node_modules\next\dist\compiled\next-server\app-route.runtime.dev.js:6:45808)
    at async ek.handle (C:\Users\kethmark\thesis\node_modules\next\dist\compiled\next-server\app-route.runtime.dev.js:6:56292)
    at async doRender (C:\Users\kethmark\thesis\node_modules\next\dist\server\base-server.js:1377:42)
    at async cacheEntry.responseCache.get.routeKind (C:\Users\kethmark\thesis\node_modules\next\dist\server\base-server.js:1599:28)
    at async DevServer.renderToResponseWithComponentsImpl (C:\Users\kethmark\thesis\node_modules\next\dist\server\base-server.js:1507:28)
    at async DevServer.renderPageComponent (C:\Users\kethmark\thesis\node_modules\next\dist\server\base-server.js:1931:24)
    at async DevServer.renderToResponseImpl (C:\Users\kethmark\thesis\node_modules\next\dist\server\base-server.js:1969:32)
    at async DevServer.pipeImpl (C:\Users\kethmark\thesis\node_modules\next\dist\server\base-server.js:920:25)
    at async NextNodeServer.handleCatchallRenderRequest (C:\Users\kethmark\thesis\node_modules\next\dist\server\next-server.js:272:17)
    at async DevServer.handleRequestImpl (C:\Users\kethmark\thesis\node_modules\next\dist\server\base-server.js:816:17)
    at async C:\Users\kethmark\thesis\node_modules\next\dist\server\dev\next-dev-server.js:339:20
    at async Span.traceAsyncFn (C:\Users\kethmark\thesis\node_modules\next\dist\trace\trace.js:154:20)
    at async DevServer.handleRequest (C:\Users\kethmark\thesis\node_modules\next\dist\server\dev\next-dev-server.js:336:24)
    at async invokeRender (C:\Users\kethmark\thesis\node_modules\next\dist\server\lib\router-server.js:174:21)
    at async handleRequest (C:\Users\kethmark\thesis\node_modules\next\dist\server\lib\router-server.js:353:24)
    at async requestHandlerImpl (C:\Users\kethmark\thesis\node_modules\next\dist\server\lib\router-server.js:377:13)
    at async Server.requestListener (C:\Users\kethmark\thesis\node_modules\next\dist\server\lib\start-server.js:141:13) {
  code: 'P5000',
  clientVersion: '5.18.0',
  meta: { modelName: 'Auth' }

I tried to use the prisma accelerate for my middleware but something happened every request has made of my api route handlers
